# All codes after Activity SetContentView call are not executed (no exception or message)

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a simple starting Android app like this:

[image]

(All text code below)

The code never hits the first breakpoint. If I put a breakpoint on the `this.SetContentView(...)` call, it will hit (but still not hit the calling btnStart line). Also, when I click the button, nothing happens at all. No exception thrown too.

What did I do wrong?

**EDIT**: I did 1 step further, adding this line of code right after receiving `btnStart`:

```
        btnStart.Text = "Abc";
```

It is not executed too. I realize, after `SetContentView`, the code is not executed anymore!

Code for MainActivity.cs:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        this.SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        var btnStart = this.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnStart);
        btnStart.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var txtContent = this.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtContent);
            var content = txtContent.Text;
            txtContent.Text = "Hello " + content;
        };
    }
```

Layout main.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:text="Start"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnStart" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtContent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you try cleaning your project then rebuilding? Try that to see if helps in any way

Comment: @apineda Yes, I did. Clean Solution -> Rebuild Solution. Still the same.

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo that can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Hello, as of now, it seems the problem only happens to my AVD emulator. I works fine on VS Emulator, BlueStacks and my real device.

Answer (score 0):

have you realized that the axml file is main.axml and you set the contentview to this.SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main). Try to change the axml file name to Main.axml. then it should run